# Generalization of Quantum information?

Tags: information-theory, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I've been working a lot with classical information theory results for my undergraduate thesis (thank you Shannon). At the same time, I am taking a course in quantum computing where we discuss briefly quantum information theory. I understand that the classical conception of information comes from the advent of electromechanical information sending and quantum information comes directly from quantum mechanics. I see these two fields as distinct but very closely related. My whole mathematical education so far has been showing me generalizations of generalizations (eg calculus becomes real/complex analysis which may become measure theory in some sense, etc). I'm curious if there is a rigorous definition of information from first principles which encompasses both classical and quantum information. Similar to how linear algebra can be derived from group theory/abstract algebra with certain structures and axioms, is there a meta understanding of information that encompasses both mainstream theories?

Comment: This is a thought provoking question. I wanted to add a few comments in order to spark more interest. My understanding of Information theory, classical or quantum , is that of a theory carved out of some probability space. We need as little as the Von Shannon entropy in order to start talking about notions of information. You will see in the classical theory that the Shannon entropy is defined via some probability measure. In quantum mechanics we can construct the analog. called the Von Neumann entropy which is built from the density operator (the analog of probability measure in quantum).